# OS X Server 4 + XCode 6.1 + CI with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, cocoapods, osx-server

Server is up with Xcode, and the bot is building the project. My only problem is that it is not using the workspace file, but the project.
I get an exception: Library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
How can I configure the bot to use the xcworkspace file?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do that in Xcode Server but you can certainly do that in [Bitrise](http://www.bitrise.io/) (I'm the CTO) - it'll auto detect the workspace file even if it's created by Cocoapods.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Tell Barnabás, Pont Systems sends its best regards ;)

Comment: Wow, what a small world :) If you're around our office and would love to grab a beer or coffee just ping us ;)